# Adding subview to UIWindow in iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uiwindow, addsubview

In one place in my app i was adding an overlay to the key window as a overlay.After updating my iPad to 8.4 that stopped working.Is there anything that needs to be considered that has been changed over the iOS Versions?

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window!!.addSubview(thankYouOverlayView)
```

P.S thankYouOverlayView can be added to self.view as subview but i need it to be at the top level.

Comment: when you say, "stopped working" do you mean that it doesn't appear or it crashes?

Comment: Adding an overlay in this manor is error prone. This might work for iOS 8.3, and as you noted, stops working in 8.4. You might want to invest some time and create a proper class or category of UIViewController which adds your overlay, instead of adding a subview to the window of the application. As a suggested fix that still uses the same method might work for iOS 8.4, but might fail in iOS 9, sending you back to square one.

Comment: actually that needs to be in the uiwindows because presented viewconrollers are dismissed while user sees that layout.

Comment: @Fennelousk App doesn't crash but the overlay does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, adding directly to the window is generally not a good idea. You *can* do it, but it's better to have a specific view and view controller that you're adding the view to.

What I have found to be effective is to create a loop that finds the top most view and view controller and add the view to that. I've never had an issue with that from iOS 6 up through the current iOS 9 beta.